# Entity Framework Concatenated Key in Lookup

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a code first project and while designing this project I have come across a problem that has stumped me, hopefully someone here will be able to propose a solution. I have three tables and they had many to many relationships with each other. so I resolved the many to many using a new entity that would be a look-up table in the database.

[image]

the problem I have is that Entity Framework won't allow me to just use the entities of A,B and C in the look-up entity it wants me to add an ID to the lookup table. This would mean that I would then be allowing duplication of data, and I do not want this.

I have tried to set the Key attribute within the POCO (not good practice but still tried) the purist will be glad to hear that this does not work so I removed it.

```
public class ABC
{
    [key]
    [column(order=1)]
    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    [key]
    [column(order=2)]
    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    [key]
    [column(order=3)]
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}
```

As this did not work I then tried to use a mappings file and used the following

```
public class ABCMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<ABC>
{
    public ABCMappings()
    {
        HasKey(x => new { A.Id, B.Id, C.Id});
    }
}
```

This also fails reporting in both cases that ABC has no key defined. If I can't do this because of EF then I guess I will have to use the ID as descried above but I would like to know why I can't do this or a solution would be great.

Comment: The first order should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the Keys in the POCO you could do the following.

```
public class ABC
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("A"), Column(order=0)]
    public int AId {get;set;}
    [Key, ForeignKey("B"), Column(order=1)]
    public int BId {get;set;}
    [Key, ForeignKey("C"), Column(order=2)]
    public int CId {get;set;}

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this led me to a potential solution I used your extra properties, and set them as the key in the Mappings section to avoid annotations in my POCO this set the table correctly but I need to test.